# Bind checklistbox from database according to category in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am facing a problem and don't know how to do it.I am unable to find any related solution. I have two relational table from where i fetch the related data using category  which seems like below  [image: Fetched Table Data]

Now the Main thing what i am unable to do that bind this fetched data into a checklist in asp.net webform.I know how to bind data from database in checklist box but here I want to bind it category wise from the above given picture table Which will be like the below image
[image]

where the category will be the header and related product will be in the checklist.

Comment: What have you tried?

Additionally, do you need to have certain boxes (pre)checked as in your image and if yes, how do we know which item should be checked?

Comment: ii ssaid i can bind the normal checklist but cant do this one and no its just image there will be only checkbox  no ppre check and user can check or not check as their wish there will only checkbox

Comment: Group them first by category and bind each group into separate checkboxlists.

Comment: i already group them like the first image now can't bind them as the we bind data in checklist  generally  as it will be dynamic  according to table

Answer (score 0):

You can create an SQL Case which returns true or false based on your query conditions. Return type must be Boolean because Checkbox works with Boolean values.